# Open source database of world locations

Tags: open-source-gis, point-of-interest, data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comprehensive list of Latitude and Longitude values of cities round the world](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21923/comprehensive-list-of-latitude-and-longitude-values-of-cities-round-the-world)

i would like to know if is out there any downloadable database of world locations,

i know there is openstreetmap db available, but i would like somenthing lighter then that, i just would like a world cities + region + nation + coordinates db, cause my intent is just to query the db to find near places to a given city.

So doesn't matter if db has cities with 1K population for example, i don't need them all, i just need the more/main important cities up to 20/30K citizens i mean and their related coordinates + region + nation , thanks i know it should be like it there isn't out there :P

Maybe someone could help me then on querying openstreetmap db to remove all not needed data !?

Comment: +1 for [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). I think they'll have exactly what you want. You'll need to learn their taxonomy for the different geographies, but if you explore a bit you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: There are numerous questions that already ask for similar datasets.  Search the [POI tag (points of interest)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poi) for the best results.

Comment: I'd change the word "source" with "access" in the title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds as if [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) has everything you need - you can [download](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt) the whole (or parts of) the database. From your description of the problem it sounds like you need cities1000.zip,

Answer (score 5):

The Natural Earth data sets may meet your needs.  Take a look at the Cultural Features http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/

The data is available at 1:10 million, 1:50 million, and 1:110 million scales and it is published under a very liberal Public Domain license.  http://www.naturalearthdata.com/about/terms-of-use/

Answer (score 4):

OpenStreetMap has an API to retrieve data.
See the manual at: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6 .

Also at openstreet maps there is some "**extracts**" like you want available.
Check if someone matchs: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Downloading